# Building an online MVC architecture description

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, yii

I would like to create for my Yii application, a site where I can describe each model, view and controller used. However, doing this for each and everyone of my classes would be an extremely long task which I believe might already be solved out there.

Is there a way to automatically create an site with each model/view/controller and its methods, so then I can add a description to it?

Comment: You want a website that lists all the models, views, and controllers used by that website?

Comment: @ktothez Not only that, I would like for each model/view/controller to be clickable, so as to go to a new page which lists information about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried phpDocumentor http://www.phpdoc.org/?  It's crawls your PHP files' comments and generates a simple website for them in the spirit of JavaDocs.

Or, better still, there is a custom extension you can use to build docs like those on the Yii site call Yii Docs Generator http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiidocsgenerator.  See the details at http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/186/how-to-generate-yii-like-documentation

Comment: AMAZING! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm gonna try implement this Yii Docs extension, have you used it yourself? Is it easy to use? THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at **[T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC)** - it uses a T4 template to generate code for each controller / method. Maybe you could utilize it.

Comment: It looks interesting! However, I am using php. And also, this tool is useful in order to not call each view/controller by name (string), using instead intellisense.. Sadly, not what I am looking for! Thank you very much anyways!!

Comment: Sorry, missed `yii` tag ;-) Another reason to switch to .NET ;-P

Comment: Having to buy Visual Studio = a reason not to switch.

Comment: You don't have to buy VS - there are free versions... And the compiler is free...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Gii module of yii. Once you create the tables it can produce models and then CRUD (create, update, delete) pages. Excluding the database there would be no programming required. And then you have the full source in a readable and documented form to manipulate and change to suite your needs.

If you wan't something a bit more advanced or custom you could extend Gii and produce some of your own templates

Answer (score 0):

Larry Ullman has a really nice series on [Learning the Yii Framework](http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/). In [part 3](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/03/configuring-yii/) of the series, he walks you through configuring Yii and enabling [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii), a web-based automated code generation tool for Yii. In [part 5](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/07/creating-models-views-and-controllers-in-yii-2/), he shows you how to use it to generate the code for your models. The whole series is a really nice introduction to Yii, I recommend it.